# Comment traduire « conference paper » ?

Tags: traduction, science

Comment traduire « *conference paper* » ? C'est un certain type de publication scientifique. Avec Google, j'ai seulement trouvé « rapport de conférence », mais je pense que ce n'est pas une traduction correcte.

Comment: *Paper* c'est un article. Ensuite ça peut varier selon le domaine scientifique (informatique ? physique ? etc.) donc à préciser.

Comment: @Laure Ingénierie.

Comment: Notez que l'angliscisme "papier" se retrouve très souvent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

« **Article de conférence** » ou « **article de congrès** », que l'on rédige souvent sous la forme « article présenté à [nom de la conférence] ».

Un *paper*, c'est un article. Une *conference*, cela dépend des communautés. En informatique¹, on parle de *conférence*. Le mot *conférence* désigne souvent l'exposé d'une personne en particulier ([TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/conf%C3%A9rence) sens C.1), mais il peut aussi désigner une réunion dans son ensemble (TLF sens B.2). Il me semble qu'en mathématiques *[congrès](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congr%C3%A8s_scientifique)* est plus répandu.

Le mot rapport ne peut pas traduire *paper*. Un « rapport de conférence », ce serait quelque chose d'écrit après la conférence, pour expliquer ce qui y a été dit et décidé. On peut aussi présenter un rapport sur un sujet à une conférence, mais ce serait un *report*, pas un *paper*.

En principe, du moins dans les disciplines avec lesquelles je suis familier, un *conference paper* en anglais comme un article de conférence en français sont revus par les pairs, contrairement à une *presentation* (présentation ou communication) qui ne l'est pas et n'a pas particulièrement d'intérêt sur un CV. Si l'on a été invité à faire cette présentation, ce qui montre que les organisateurs de la conférence vous ont fait confiance, c'est une « présentation invitée » ou « conférence invitée » ou « communication invitée ».

¹  <sub>Source : j'ai été chercheur en informatique en France.</sub>